# How to transmit video card output wirelessly to a large screen TV?

Tags: wireless-networking, media

I have a PC running Windows Vista (probably will upgrade to Windows 7 shortly) in one room of my home and a large screen HDTV in another.  I can't run a line from the PC to the TV for various reasons and *most* of the time I'll continue to use the PC with its own monitor; but there are times I'd like to switch to the big screen (for gaming or occasionally for writing.)

Is there a device that I can set up that will allow me to use my wireless network to broadcast the screen to the TV?  I have a wireless keyboard/mouse so if I can get the video to send, I should be able to just move between rooms. I looked at the SlingCatcher but I don't know that it would work with sending game video. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a [wireless computer to TV adapter](http://www.ramelectronics.net/audiovideo/htpc-media-pc-mac/pc-mac-tv-connectivity/gwb-4000/prodGWB4000.html).

Answer (score 1):

Theres this http://www.x10.com/products/x10_vk73a.htm But its kinda buggy :(